# How to parse json include map and arraylist in java object

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-stream, objectmapper

I am using java8 stream api and want to parse one Json file and then uses stream api to get desired output.

Sample Json :

```
{
  "map1":{
    "Test1":
    [
      "1"
    ],
    "Test2":
    [
      "2",
      "3"
    ]
  },
  "map2":{
    "Test3":[
      "4",
      "5"
    ]
  }
}
```

java Program : Here assume map is populating json file perfect fine. Now when I am running the following program it throws error at line `.flatMap(e -> Stream.of(((Map.Entry)e).getKey())) )`.

```
Map map = objectMapper.readValue("test", Map.class);

ArrayList response = (ArrayList) map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(((Map.Entry)e).getValue()))
        .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(((Map)e).keySet()))
        .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(((Map.Entry)e).getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Error :
[image]

here I want after procession through stream api it should result.

```
List of [Test1, Test2, Test3]
```

can someone see this piece of code or suggest something else if it does not work well.

Comment: What about `map.values().stream().flatMap(m -> ((Map) m).keySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());` ?

Comment: what if I want to flat values like 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the object mapper's `readValue()` method using a `TypeReference` to create a `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`, then extract the desired result:

```
Collection<String> response = ((Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>) objectMapper.readValue(sampleJson,
        new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>>() {})) 
        .values() // to get a collection of Map<String, List<String>>
        .stream().map(m -> m.keySet()) // to get the key set of the map which has the values we want
        .flatMap(Set::stream) // to flatten the collection of sets 
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // to collect each value to a list
```

Output:

```
[Test1, Test2, Test3]
```

Comment: what if I want to flat values like 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Then you should get `m.values()` instead of `m.keySet()` : `.values().stream().flatMap(m -> m.values().stream()).flatMap(Collection::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

```java
ArrayList response = (ArrayList) map.values()
                                            .stream()
                                            .map(it -> ((Map)it).keySet())
                                            .flatMap(it -> ((Set<?>) it).stream())
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```